# React component not refreshing content on state change [Next.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, state

So i have the problem that my Header component is not changing content on state change. I want to display user `Profile` when state changes, but unfortunately it doesn't change content immediately, but it does after page refresh/route.push to other page.

Here is the function i fetch data with. It triggers when URL query have `code` param to finish auth flow and then fetch data, or when access token is already in local storage then it just fetches data.

```
export default function Header(props) {
const userProfile = async() => { 
    if (query.code && !userId) { 
      await handleAuthuser();
      const { profile, balance, userStatus } = await getUserData();
      setMoneyButtonData(profile, balance, userStatus);
    }

    if (storage.getItem('mb_js_client:oauth_access_token') && !userId) {
      const { profile, balance, userStatus } = await getUserData();
      setMoneyButtonData(profile, balance, userStatus);
    } 
  }
  userProfile();
```

```
function setMoneyButtonData(_profile, _balance, _userStatus) {
    setUserId(_profile.id);
    ...
  }
```

Then i have condition in function component `return`:

```
<a>
 {!userId ? <LoginDialog /> :
  <Profile name={userName} userId={userId} primaryPaymail={userPrimaryPaymail} userEmail={userEmail} userAvatar={userAvatarUrl} userAmount={userAmount} userCurrency={userCurrency} userStatus={userStatus}/> }
</a>
```

I tried using `useEffect()`, i tried `setTimeout` but it didn't work. I think it have something to do with client/server side rendering. What can i do to fetch this data before component render and display it?

Comment: Can you please show the full code for you component? It's hard to fully understand with just parts of it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use react hook useEffect

```
  useEffect( async()=>{

    if (query.code && !userId) { 
       await handleAuthuser();
       const { profile, balance, userStatus } = await getUserData();
       setMoneyButtonData(profile, balance, userStatus);
    }

    if (storage.getItem('mb_js_client:oauth_access_token') && !userId) {
        const { profile, balance, userStatus } = await getUserData();
        setMoneyButtonData(profile, balance, userStatus);
    } 
  }
},[])
```

It will automatically work when your jsx is load.

Comment: for use `await` behaivour directly inside `useEffect` you should declare a child `async` function, not the whole effect. `useEffect(()=>{ (async () { ... use await here ... })() }, [])`

Comment: Unfortunately useEffect with [] seems to not have access to query.code params, i have to use [router.isReady], but again this way the data is not available @HagaiHarari can you elaborate a bit more about child async functions?